# Piecewise function with set builder notation

Tags: functions

I want to define a function takes takes a set, and outputs another set while modifying some elements. The question is, how do I express such a function using set builder notation?

Let $g:B\to A$,  $g(S)$ is a set that contains $(x+1)$ for every $x$ in $S$ that is bigger or equal to $7$ and $x$ for every $x$ in $S$ that is less than $7$.

Also, given $A\ =\ P\left(N\backslash7\right),\ B\ =\ P\left(N\right)\ \backslash\ P\left(\left\{7\right\}\right)$, how would you prove the function is injective? Because it feels kind of trivial which makes it a pain for me to prove..

Comment: Do you mean $g:S\to A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}x< 7\to x,\\x\ge7\to x+1\end{cases}.$$

Then

$$A=\{x\in S:f(x)\}.$$

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could first define a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by
$$ f = \{ (x,x+1) \mid x \in \mathbb{N}, x \geq 7 \} \cup \{ (x,x) \mid x \in \mathbb{N}, x < 7 \} $$
in set-builder notation. Now the function $g$ you want to define is
$$ g = \left\{ \left(S, \{ y \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists x \in S : (x,y) \in f \} \right) \mid S \in P(\mathbb{N}) \right\} \,. $$

By the way... It's recommended that you avoid asking two separate questions in a single post. I suggest you post your second question on injectivity separately!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Someone goes around mass downvoting my posts for some reason. Thanks for your help! I fixed your score. :)